# Gradle will not build in command prompt gradle -v

Tags: cmd, gradle, prompt

Gradle shows up in echo %PATH% no problem.. 
It has has it's own directory in Program Files, however when I attempt:

```
gradle -v ..
```

It responds: 'gradle' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file..

I am trying to get this to work in conjunction with an Eclipse Simpleservlet project..

Comment: Sounds like the path is wrong then. It's definitely not a Gradle specific problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just solved the problem. My PATH variable value was like:

> path1;path2,path3,gradlebinpath

I replaced `,` with `;` and added a `;` at the end of the value and it just worked. The final value looked like:

> path1;path2;path3;gradlebinpath;

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to follow https://gradle.org/install/ for windows then you might want to verify if the path variable was set properly or not, because for me the path to 'bin' folder in gradle was different from the documentation which says `C:\Gradle\gradle-6.8.1\bin` at the time of writing this.

- Open 'This PC'
- right click and open 'Properties'
- Goto 'Advanced System Settings' on the left panel -> Environment Variables.
- Find 'Path' under 'System Variables'
- Edit
- Click on Browse and then search for your 'bin' folder in the `C:\Gradle` folder. For me it was `C:\Gradle\gradle-6.8.1-bin\gradle-6.8.1\bin`.

Save your changes. If the terminal still does not show expected output on `gradle -v` then try restarting the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

In window's Environment variables, add to path the address upto Gradle/bin, i.e. at the end of path variable add ";(path upto Gradle)/bin".

Answer (score 1):

PATH needs to contain a directory where gradle executable is located (not the gradle itself).

Comment: Based upon 'project instructions' download of the 'binary' files was all that was necessary.. at 11:23 in this video .. https://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/mobilecloud/source_videos/BulidWithGradleTutorial_Corrected.mp4... the 'Gradle binaries' which now live in the win7 64 'program files' directory ..appear to imply that files are executable.. *note.. the Gradle Plugin for Eclipse Luna., works fine.... it's only at the build of the 'binaries' from within the command prompt .. where it all goes sideways..

Comment: Sorted.. had to go to the bin file to run gradle -v. Program Files\gradle-2.0\bin  gradle -v..

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to move gradle-x.x.x folder to C:\Gradle.
You can use winrar or any archiver and unzip all the contents of the gradle-x.x.x into C:\Gradle then in your windows environment variable, right under 'system variables', click on 'path', then 'Edit'.
In the New popup window, add C:\Gradle\bin
Then click on 'Ok'..
After you must have finished,  RESTART YOUR SYSTEM, then open command prompt And run 'gradle -v'...
The version with build time and other stuffs will show!

Answer (score 0):

In path under system variable add

;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin
or
";%GRADLE_HOME%\bin"

After adding path in Gradle_Home with new variable.

Answer (score -1):

You need to give the path till `gradle.bat` file.

download [gradle.zip](https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-bin.zip)

Unzip it to any location , example:

> F:\Learning\GradleTutorials\gradle-6.0.1-bin\gradle-6.0.1\bin

[image: path]

Then type `gradle -v or gradle -version` in a fresh cmd window. Sometimes machine reboot may required.